# How can I delete multiple rows from two tables with three primary keys?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to delete multiple rows selected from checkbox from two tables namely pdn_subscription_ctx and subscriber_profile which have three primary keys mcc,mnc and msin from mysqldb but I could not able to do that. here is the command I wrote:

```
DELETE x.*
     , p.* 
  FROM pdn_subscription_ctx x
  JOIN subscriber_profile p
    ON x.mcc = p.mcc 
   AND x.mnc = p.mnc 
   AND x.msin = p.msin 
 WHERE (p.mcc,p.mnc,p.msin) IN ( (244, 56, "0x1000000004"),(244, 59, "0x1000000002"),(289, 88, "0x1000000001" ) )
```

It does not delete any rows and does not show errors either.
Here are the sample data for pri.key fields: mcc mnc msin 244 56 0x1000000004

Comment: Start with any existing example of a DELETE query

Comment: Sample date and table schemas would be helpful.

Comment: Also, for this to not show errors, you must be suppressing errors

Comment: schema: CREATE TABLE `pdn_subscription_ctx` (
  `mcc` smallint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `mnc` smallint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `msin` binary(5) NOT NULL,
  `ctx_id` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `apn` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pgw_allocation_type` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vplmn_dynamic_address_allowed` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `eps_pdn_subscribed_charging_characteristics` binary(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pdn_addr_type` bit(2) DEFAULT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (`mcc`,`mnc`,`msin`,`ctx_id`)
)

Answer (score 0):

Your code works just fine assuming your model and mine are equivalent

```
drop table if exists pdn_subscription_ctx , subscriber_profile ;
create table pdn_subscription_ctx(mcc int,mnc int ,msin varchar(20));
create table subscriber_profile(mcc int,mnc int ,msin varchar(20));
insert into pdn_subscription_ctx values
(244, 56, "0x1000000004"),(244, 59, "0x1000000002"),(289, 88, "0x1000000001");
insert into subscriber_profile values
(244, 56, "0x1000000004"),(244, 59, "0x1000000002"),(289, 88, "0x1000000001");

DELETE pdn_subscription_ctx.*, subscriber_profile.* 
FROM pdn_subscription_ctx 
INNER JOIN subscriber_profile ON pdn_subscription_ctx.mcc = subscriber_profile.mcc AND 
                pdn_subscription_ctx.mnc = subscriber_profile.mnc AND 
                pdn_subscription_ctx.msin = subscriber_profile.msin 
WHERE (subscriber_profile.mcc,subscriber_profile.mnc,subscriber_profile.msin) IN ( (244, 56, "0x1000000004"),(244, 59, "0x1000000002"),(289, 88, "0x1000000001" ))
;

select * from pdn_subscription_ctx;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

select * from subscriber_profile; 
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I dont know it did not work for me here is the query results:  0 rows affected. (Query took 0.0005 seconds.)
DELETE pdn_subscription_ctx.*, subscriber_profile.* FROM pdn_subscription_ctx INNER JOIN subscriber_profile ON pdn_subscription_ctx.mcc = subscriber_profile.mcc AND pdn_subscription_ctx.mnc = subscriber_profile.mnc AND pdn_subscription_ctx.msin = subscriber_profile.msin WHERE (subscriber_profile.mcc,subscriber_profile.mnc,subscriber_profile.msin) IN ( (244, 56, "0x1000000004"),(244, 59, "0x1000000002"),(289, 88, "0x1000000001" ))

Comment: Works fine for me with your additional schema information (if msin is binary(12) so if you are getting 0 rows affected I would suspect the binary field msin. can't tell without data.AND binary(5) is too small to hold the values you are testing against.

Comment: mcc mnc msin ctx_id apn pgw_allocation_type vplmn_dynamic_address_allowed eps_pdn_subscribed_charging_characteristics pdn_addr_type pdn_addr subscribed_apn_ambr_dl subscribed_apn_ambr_up qci qos_allocation_retention_priority_level qos_allocation_retention_priority_preemption_capability qos_allocation_retention_priority_preemption_vulnerability served_party_ipv4_addr 
244 56  0 internet 0 0  00  100000 100000 9 15 0 0 NULL 
244 59  0 internet 0 0  00  100000 100000 9 15 0 0 NULL 
289 88  0 internet 0 0  00  100000 100000 9 15 0 0 NULL 
283 5  0 internet 0 0  00  100000 100000 9 15 0 0 NU

Comment: I only need to see the relevant 4 fields and you should add these as text to the question not as comments (or to sql fiddle)

Comment: Solved. the problem was with the msin field which was binary data type but I treat it as varchar data type. anyways thank you for your help p.Salmon